# Copy a solution in visual studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I have a working solution, and I would like to copy it and paste in a new folder.  I am creating a new version of the site, and want to build on a "copy" of the solution.  But when I do it, all the paths are lost and it doesn't work.  What am I missing.  What is the process to copy a working solution and get it to work from new location?

Comment: You didn't only copy the solutionfile, did you? If you copy the whole directory it shouldn't be a problem. Besides, have you considered a source control system like SVN to manage the versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the solution and the related projects. If the paths don't work then edit the SLN with a text editor to fix the paths.